# imagebutton in gridview...can't get correct row key

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

I'm developing a C# asp.net 4.5 web page.

I have a GridView to which I've bound the results of a linq query using BoundFields and TemplateFields.  All that works fine.

But I also have an ImageButton within a TemplateField in each row. I need to have that button run some code using the data key of the row the ImageButton was on.

I've tried using the DataKeyNames but when I debug the DataKey value is always null.

I've also tried an OnClick method but I don't know how to retrieve the key from the GridView.

EDIT: Here's the GridView code

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BorderColor="#336699" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="10pt"OnRowCreated="GridView1_RowCreated" DataKeyNames="titleid" EnablePersistedSelection="True" EnableViewState="False" >
```

Here's the ImageButton TemplateField:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText ="Save">
     <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:ImageButton ID ="btnSave" runat="server" OnClick="btnSave_Click"CommandName="SaveTitle" ImageUrl="~/images/download.jpg" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DisplayIndex %>' />
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: Show your Work.. and point out the actual problem in that..

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1):

Do not try to do both a click event handler and a command name, but instead just the command; like this:

```
<ItemTemplate>
      <asp:ImageButton ID ="btnSave" runat="server" 
                       CommandName="SaveTitle" 
                       ImageUrl="~/images/download.jpg" 
                       CommandArgument='<%# Container.DisplayIndex %>' />
</ItemTemplate>
```

Also, make sure to set the `OnRowCommand` value in your grid view, like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
              BorderColor="#336699" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" 
              CellPadding="3" Font-Names="Verdana" 
              Font-Size="10pt"
              OnRowCreated="GridView1_RowCreated" DataKeyNames="titleid" 
              EnablePersistedSelection="True" EnableViewState="False"
              OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand">
```

Finally, implement the `GridView1_RowCommand` method, like this:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    // If multiple buttons are used in a GridView control, use the
    // CommandName property to determine which button was clicked.
    if(e.CommandName == "SaveTitle")
    {
        // Do logic here to save title

    }
}
```

---

UPDATE:

Instead of using the `Container.DisplayIndex` for the command argument, use the `TitleID` value of the binding source (LINQ query), like this:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:ImageButton ID ="btnSave" runat="server" 
                     CommandName="SaveTitle" 
                     ImageUrl="~/images/download.jpg" 
                     CommandArgument='<%# Eval("TitleID") %>' />
</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: That seems to have worked up to a point...I changed the CommandArgument to this:  

    CommandArgument='<%#Eval("TitleID")%>'

and I'm getting a key in the RowCommand method but it doesn't match the row I clicked on. In fact none of the keys match any of the rows displayed.

Comment: For example...the first row I've verified in SQL should have a TitleID of 1027654.  

But when I click the imagebutton in the first row and check the value in the GridView1_RowCommand method...the e.CommandSource.CommandArgument the value is 1025695 which is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass DataKey Id instead of DataKeyNames to CommandArgument of Image Button and value of that you can get on Button's click event you can get value of that on code behind.

Try this.

Comment: I've tried using the CommandArguement but when I click the button it doesn't call the GridView1_RowCommand which I understand it should call.

Answer (score 0):

string id = ((ImageButton)sender).CommandArgument.ToString();
try this